# How to create a UI button to add a custom property to an Empty object?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I want to create a button  create an empty object with some custom properties that I may change in the moment of creation.

Here's the code to create the button and the empty object:

```
import bpy
import os
import FUNCION as lib
import imp

imp.reload(lib)

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear()

def initSceneProperties(scn):
    bpy.types.Scene.PropVelx = FloatProperty(
        name = "Velx",
        description = "Velocidad en el eje X",
        default = 1, 
        min = 0,
        max = 20)        
    bpy.types.Scene.PropVely = FloatProperty(
        name = "Vely",
        description = "Velocidad en el eje Y",
        default = 1, 
        min = 0,
        max = 20)        
    bpy.types.Scene.PropVelz = FloatProperty(
        name = "Velz",
        description = "Velocidad en el eje Z",
        default = 1, 
        min = 0,
        max = 20)

class PanelBotonEmpty(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Colocar Empty" #Name
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"  #Space 
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"   #Región of the panel 
    bl_category = "GIM"        #Name of the custom tag
    bl_context = "objectmode"  #Mode of view to see the panel

    def draw_header(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="", icon="PARTICLE_POINT") #Icon type

    def draw(self, context):
        #Añadimos una columna c
        c= self.layout.column(align=True)
        #Add the button
        c.operator("object.create_empty", text="Add Empty with custom properties") 
        #Add the selectors
        c.prop(context.scene, 'PropVelx')
        c.prop(context.scene, 'PropVely')
        c.prop(context.scene, 'PropVelz')

class  createEmpty(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.create_empty" #Listener
    bl_label = "Add Empty with custom properties"
    bl_options = {"UNDO"}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        #Get the value of the global 
        velx = context.scene.PropVelx
        vely = context.scene.PropVely
        velz = context.scene.PropVelz
        #Call the function that créate the Empty
        lib.add_empty()

        return{"FINISHED"}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(createEmpty)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PanelBotonEmpty)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CreateEmpty)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PanelBotonEmpty)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register() 

def add_empty(velx, vely, velz):
    myEmpty = bpy.data.objects.new('empty_' + bpy.context.object.name, None)
    #Posición del objeto 
    myEmpty.location = bpy.context.object.location    
    #Type
    myEmpty.empty_draw_type = 'ARROWS'
    #Create and asing the properties
    myEmpty["Velx"] = velx
    myEmpty["Vely"] = vely
    myEmpty["Velz"] = velz
    #Link the object to the scene
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(myEmpty)
    #Update the scene
    bpy.context.scene.update()
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Does this code gives an error or what?

Comment: Could I suggest passing the empty name and  scene to the utility method, and return a ref to the newly created empty.  Are you wanting to simply add a custom prop like `empty["foo"] = "bar"` ?

Comment: I just wanting to add a custom prop, that was the solution @batFINGER